# Factory Girl associated object instantiation [using devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, factory-bot

I have three models user (author), which is incorporating devise logic:

## app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
end
```

question:

## app/models/question.rb

```
# Model for Question
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

and answer:

## app/models/answer.rb

```
# Model for Answer
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'

  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
  validates :question_id, presence: true
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

and their factories:

## spec/factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do    
  sequence :email do |n|
    "email-#{n}@example.com"
  end

  sequence :password do |n|
    "testpassword#{n}"
  end

  factory :user, aliases: [:author] do
    email
    # tried sequence generator and fixed password - both have no impact on result
    # password '1234567890'
    # password_confirmation '1234567890'
    password
  end

end
```

## spec/factories/answers.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :answer do
    body 'Answer Body'
    author
    question
  end

  factory :nil_answer, class: 'Answer' do
    question
    body nil
  end
end
```

## spec/factories/questions.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question do
    title 'Question Title'
    body 'Question Body'
    author

    factory :question_with_answers  do
      after(:create) do |question|
        # changing create_list to create has no impact on result
        # create_list(:answer, 2, question: question)
        create(:answer, question: question)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

test code:

## spec/features/delete_answer_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Delete answer', %q{
  By some reason
  As an authenticated user
  I want to delete answer
} do

  given(:question) { create(:question_with_answers) }
  given(:user) { create(:user) }
  given(:ans) { create(:answer) }

  scenario 'Answer author password should not be nil' do
    expect(question.answers.first.author.password).to_not be_nil
    # question.author.password and ans.author.password return not nil
    # I need password to do:
    # visit new_user_session_path
    # fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    # fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    # click_on 'Log in'
  end 
end
```

Can anyone explain why the following given statement:

```
given(:question) { create(:question_with_answers) }
```

creates question object that:

```
question.author.password #=> '1234567890'
```

but:

```
question.answers.first.author.password #=> nil
```

why method "create" instantiates author of question properly (field password is set), but "create_list" inside "after" callback creates author in answer with nil fields?

rails 4.2.5, ruby 2.3.0, devise 3.5.6, warden 1.2.6, factory_girls_rails 4.6.0 (4.5.0)

Comment: seems like a _bug_.. :)

Comment: Something might happen somewhere else which causes this problem. Can you post more code such as a test that reproduces the problem, and the code for the question / answer models?

Comment: Included more code& If needed can give link on GitHub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise (and most authentication libraries) encrypt the password and don't allow you to access passwords from models retrieved from the database. The password may be temporarily available through an in-memory reader method, but won't be available if you retrieve the record from the database.

If you do:

```
user = User.new(password: "example")
p user.password
```

I'm guessing you'll see `"example"`.

But if you do:

```
user = User.first
p user.password
```

I bet you'll see `nil` (assuming you have user records in your database).

When you query an association proxy like `question.answers.first.author`, it's going to the database again to find the answer and author. That means you're using a different instance, which no longer has the password available.

Comment: You're right. In-memory property reader misleaded me ) Thank you very much!